# is this a bad / inelegant way to handle this? Would backbone or ember help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, ember.js

I have a lot of the following types of html / jquery and am wondering if there is a better way to handle it.  I am trying to separate the binding of html, instantiation of object, a processing (post and calling view rendering), and a view layer that deletes out the container with the id.

html:

```
<span data-global-id="1" class="remove-item">remove</span>
```

event capture.js:

```
$('.remove-item').click(function(){
  var l=get_remove_item($(this));
  process(l); // this does the posting based upoint values in objectction

});
```

object-creation.js:

```
function get_remove_item(v){
    t={};
    t.action='remove-item';

    t.global_id=v.data('global-id');
    console.log(t);
    return t;
}
```

process.js:

```
function process(l){
  // will post the data
  var f_name = s.replace (/-/g,"_");  // replace space or comma by underscore
  f_name=f_name + "_view";
  var str=window[f_name](r);

}
```

view.js:

```
remove_item_view(){
  // go back and delete out container with global_id value
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Would backbone or ember handle this better? In what way?

thx

Comment: You might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I guess I'm not really looking for optimization of code - just hacked this together in like an hour or two. Feel like it should be better

Answer (score 1):

Backbone would help organize the app and make updating the view easier. Ember would make things even simpler than Backbone. Because of Ember's binding, you wouldn't have remove the element from the DOM. You'd just delete the model and Ember would update the view for you.